# why 'example_size' can't be found in the code?

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle

```
import  numpy as np

def data_iter_random(data_indices, num_steps, batch_size):
    example_size = len(data_indices)/num_steps
    epoch_size = example_size/batch_size
    example = [data_indices[i*num_steps:i*num_steps + num_steps] 
              for i in range(int(example_size))]
    shuffle_example = np.random.shuffle(example)
    print(shuffle_example)


data_iter_random(list(range(30)), 5, 2)
```

The output is `None`

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: The title might need to be changed since that's too specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `np.random.shuffle` modifies the sequence in-place. From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html):

> Modify a sequence in-place by shuffling its contents.

Simply print `example`:

```
import numpy as np


def data_iter_random(data_indices, num_steps, batch_size):
    example_size = len(data_indices) / num_steps
    epoch_size = example_size / batch_size
    example = [data_indices[i * num_steps:i * num_steps + num_steps]
               for i in range(int(example_size))]
    np.random.shuffle(example)
    print(example)


data_iter_random(list(range(30)), 5, 2)
```

**Output**

```
[[25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `np.random.shuffle` is a "in-place" method.

- so no need to assign
- does it in-place
- docs say: "Modify a sequence in-place by shuffling its contents."

So do:

```
np.random.shuffle(example)
print(example)
```

For those lines.

Full code:

```
import  numpy as np

def data_iter_random(data_indices, num_steps, batch_size):
    example_size = len(data_indices)/num_steps
    epoch_size = example_size/batch_size
    example = [data_indices[i*num_steps:i*num_steps + num_steps] 
              for i in range(int(example_size))]
    np.random.shuffle(example)
    print(example)


data_iter_random(list(range(30)), 5, 2)
```

Output:

```
[[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

There are very few functions like this.